# How to replace enum type in H2 database?

Tags: java, mysql, h2

MySQL dialect:

```
CREATE TABLE My_Table ( my_column enum ('first', 'second', ... 'last'));
```

H2 dialect:

```
CREATE TABLE My_Table ( my_column ? ('first', 'second', ... 'last'));
```

What type is equivalent in H2 too the `enum` type from MySQL?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but would you could do is use a check constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE My_Table(my_column varchar(255) 
    check (my_column in ('first', 'second', 'last')));

-- fails:
insert into My_Table values('x');

-- ok:
insert into My_Table values('first');
```

This will work in H2, Apache Derby, PostgreSQL, HSQLDB, and even SQLite. I didn't test other databases.

Comment: By the way, it's possible that an enum and a reference table is more efficient.

Comment: The catch is that there is no way to enumerate the possible values with this solution (though he may not need it).

Comment: You mean you don't know the possible values? How could you use enum then? Is your example correct?

Comment: I mean you can't get a list of the accepted values in any way, except by looking at the constraint.

Answer (score 5):

There is none; still, `enum` is not a great solution in any case, just use a a reference table.

Comment: Minus 1 for "enum is not a great solution in any case" without reasoning or reference.

Comment: The `enum` type can be required for many reasons. A couple of examples: 1) matching a test H2 database structure to an existing, production, database that cannot be altered and requires this type; 2) removing the burden of joining tables and handling inserts/updates in reference tables when the `enum` field is strongly typed, whose options are not prompt to change.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like H2 has enums: http://www.h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#enum_type

So the exact same syntax should work. (I don't know how closely the semantics match.)

Comment: It does have support now, [as of **version 1.4.195**, released on 2017-04-23](http://www.h2database.com/html/changelog.html), but did not have when the question was written. Maybe you want to clarify in your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Upgrade h2 jar

H2 maven repository:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h2database/h2

jar versions:

1.4.196 Central (Jun, 2017) - enum support (tested)

1.4.192 Central (May, 2016) - lack of enum support (also tested)

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem and solved it by creating a separate table and foreign key constraint.

```
CREATE TABLE My_Enum_Table (
    my_column varchar(255) UNIQUE
);

INSERT INTO My_Enum_Table (my_column)
VALUES
    ('First'),
    ('Second'),
    ...
    ('Last');

CREATE TABLE My_Table (
   my_column varchar(255),
   FOREIGN KEY (my_column) REFERENCES My_Enum_Table (my_column)
);
```

That way when you try to do an `INSERT` into `My_Table` it will do a foreign key check to make sure the value you're inserting is in `My_Enum_Table`.

There are some trade-offs here though:

- PROS

  - You can still interact with this the same way you would an `ENUM`.
  - You also get a little extra flexibility in the sense that you can add another value without having to alter table definitions.
- CONS

  - This is likely slower than an `ENUM` since it has to do a table look-up.  Realistically though since the table should have a reasonably small number of rows this is probably fairly negligible.  Adding an index to `My_Table.my_column` may help with this.
  - This prevents the need to join with the reference table but with basically the same level of complexity from a database perspective.  Though this probably isn't a big deal unless you're concerned about cluttering your database with another table.
  - This also requires you to use an engine that support foreign keys, such as `INNODB`.  I'm not sure if this is really a CON but I suppose it could be for someone with specialized needs.

Answer (score 0):

This is now supported on H2, you can create a table with an enum column and even alter the enum later if needed.

```
CREATE TABLE example (
    "example" TEXT,
    "state" ENUM (
         'CREATED',
         'DELETED'
     )
);

ALTER TABLE example ALTER COLUMN "state" ENUM (
    'CREATED',
    'USED',
    'DELETED'
);
```